# Why xslt producing undesired results

Tags: xml, xslt

My xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="soapenv:Body//*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | *" />
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="soapenv:Body//@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Input:

```
<soapenv:Body>
    <Test asdf="asdfasdf">
        <Hope>asdf</Hope>
    </Test>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Output:

```
<Test asdf="asdfasdf">
    <Hope>asdf</Hope>
    asdf
</Test>
```

My questions is, why am I getting the extra asdf text after the Hope element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `Test` element is matched by the `<xsl:template match="soapenv:Body//*">`, which creates a `Test` element in the output, applies templates to its children (copying the `Hope` element) and then appends a text node containing the string value of the `Test` element itself - this is the concatenation of all its descendant text nodes, including the one inside `Hope`.

You could fix this by making the `<xsl:value-of>` only fire when the element in question has no element children, either by wrapping it in an

```
<xsl:if test="not(*)">
```

or by using a separate template for `soapenv:Body//*[*]`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to get rid of the namespace. (*Why? This should not actually be necessary!*)

Consider a more idiomatic approach.

```
<!-- 1) always try to start off with the identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- 2) only create templates for nodes that need extra processing -->
<xsl:template match="soapenv:*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Result with your input:

```
<Body>
    <Test asdf="asdfasdf">
        <Hope>asdf</Hope>
    </Test>
</Body>
```

---

Edit: If you just want to start the output at the body contents, use:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/*" />
</xsl:template>
```